# how do you trigger events in a routes from the outside?

Tags: ember.js

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  events:
    someEvent: (param) ->
      doSth()
```

I would like to test routes events with Jasmine but calling:

```
App.get('ApplicationController').send 'someEvent'
```

brings me an error.

Answer (score 1):

During testing, you can access instances by using container lookup:

**Controllers**

`App.__container__.lookup('controller:controllerName')`

**Routes**

`App.__container__.lookup('route:routeName')`

In your case, you would need to do:

`App.__container__.lookup('controller:application').send('someEvent');`

Or:

`App.__container__.lookup('router:main').send('someEvent');`